# MYSQL multiple join on same table with control field

Tags: mysql, join, table-relationships

I have the following table structure:

[image]
The **registration** table, indicates the type of client's contract, if is checked (1) it means that the client is directly related to the **class** table, if not (0), it means that the client is related to a **group** and the group is related to a class.

> **EDIT** When the control is 1, the id_group on registration table is null, it means that the client don't belong to a group, and have
>   individual classes.

What I need, is to get the following result:

> Client_name | 54 classes | 3 with **status** 0 | 51 with **status** 1

Where the number of classes is the **sum** of (classes related directly to registration table (**control** 1) with classes related to the group table (**control** 0))

I have this schema working with multiple queries, I load every client, then I load his classes, and count the classes **status**, but it's taking too much of the server, I need this result in a single database query.

Is there a way to get this result?

Comment: Try this:
`SELECT
  client.name,
  COUNT(class.id),
  COUNT(class.status)
FROM
  client
  INNER JOIN registration ON (client.id = registration.id)
  INNER JOIN class ON (class.id_group = registration.id_group AND class.id_registration = registration.id)
GROUP BY
  class.status`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent thanks for your answer, I have edited the text to explain to you, why your solution won't work! When the control is 1, the id_group is null, so, I can't join based on this.

Comment: You can remove `class.id_group = registration.id_group AND` from the ON clause and it should work. isn't it?